# Return 418 from WCF REST webget

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to know if it's possible to return a 418 from a WCF service. I've tried making an operation contract that returns a HttpResponseMessage, but that only accepts a HttpStatusCode as a parameter for status codes, and they've tragically forgotton to add 418 to that enum.

Does anyone have a solution to this? It's for a school project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

`HttpStatusCode` is just an `enum` type. I don't know why you're interested in 418 (hur hur April 1) but any integer can be cast to any enum type, so you can just `return (HttpStatusCode)418`.

Answer (score 0):

Since 418 is not included in the enum you can use reflection on the HttpResponseMessage object to force the HttpStatusCode property to the value 418.

Something like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage message;
message.GetType().GetProperty("StatusCode").SetValue(message, (object)418);
```

Maybe you'll even add this too ;)

```
    message.ReasonPhrase = "I'm a teapot.";
```

Comment: Why would you use reflection for something that a simple cast can do?

Comment: You're right. Previously I thought there was there was an issue with type checking with enums.